# Azure - Sentry's raven npm package not installing

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, sentry, raven

I am using CircleCI to build the project and push it to a local repository provided by Azure's Web app. Up until I added `raven` as a package to repository everything worked fine, but suddenly, this single package is refusing to be installed on azure - with no error.

Even though when I connect to the console on Azure and check `package.json` I can see that `raven` is enlisted in dependencies (I made sure it is not in dev), for some reason it is never in node_modules.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

For what it's worth, build is being done on Ubuntu 14 (Circle), and it is being deployed to Windows Web App (Azure), however I fail to see how it could be relevant if `node_modules` are being installed for every step anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push a commit to Azure remote repo, the Azure deployment task will 
get the `package.json` and automatically install `dependencies` by running the following deployment script:

```
:: 3. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

I am able to install [raven-js](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js) by putting it to `package.json` and deploy my app to Azure Web App via Local Git repository.

Here is my testing screenshot:

[image]

[image]

If you don't want to deploy your app via SCM, you'll need to go to the root of your app and execute the command `npm install --production` manually in Kudu Debug console which can be accessed by: `https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

[image]

Comment: Hm, I just tried it with another blank project and indeed it does seem to be working properly. Must mean that there is an issue elsewhere. Thank you for the reply!